# Website with multiple redirects

Tags: http, redirection, url

I am trying to understand the flow of HTTP Headers during website redirection. In case of a single redirect, the 301 Permanently Moved or similar status is straight forward. In case of websites which redirect a user multiple times, I want to understand what the headers look like.

I need help with getting a small list of websites which redirect the user multiple times. Any ideas? TIA.

Comment: When a redirect occurs, the browser is instructed to load a new URL(page). If multiple redirects occur its simply a matter of each URL sending a single request to another URL, the headers all look similar.

Answer (score 1):

An example would be the share URL of your question, with an added `www` subdomain.

What happens:

1. [`https://www.superuser.com/q/1471861/`](https://www.superuser.com/q/1471861/) 301-redirects to
   [`https://superuser.com/q/1471861/`](https://superuser.com/q/1471861/) to remove the `www` subdomain.
2. [`https://superuser.com/q/1471861/`](https://superuser.com/q/1471861/) 302-redirects to
   [`https://superuser.com/questions/1471861/website-with-multiple-redirects`](https://superuser.com/questions/1471861/website-with-multiple-redirects), which is the "final" URL of the question page (HTTP status 200).

There is nothing special about a chain of redirects, it’s just one redirect after the other. The browser requests a document under a URL, learns that it’s available from another URL, requests the document under this URL, repeat (up to a browser-specific limit, e.g., [to prevent infinite loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26951935/1591669)).